# MySQL not using indexes

Tags: mysql, index, collation

My query does not seem to bother for using indexes.
Collations are the same on each table.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT SUM(it.revenue) FROM invoice_items AS it 
INNER JOIN invoice AS i ON i.id = it.invoice_id
WHERE i.customer_id = 123
AND it.manufacturer_id = 45
AND i.created_at BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-31'
```

It should have only 400 rows, and instead, it counts all possible rows.

```
"id"    "select_type"   "table" "type"  "possible_keys" "key"   "key_len"   "ref"   "rows"  "Extra"
"1" "SIMPLE"    "i" "ref"   "PRIMARY,created_at,id_customer_id,customer_id" "customer_id"   "4" "const" "36464" "Using where"
"1" "SIMPLE"    "it"    "ref"   "invoice_id,manufacturer_id,invoice_id_manufacturer_id" "invoice_id"    "4" "comercial.i.id"    "1" "Using where"
```

Tried even force and use index syntaxes, but no luck, what am I doing wrong?

**Update**:
Adding show create tables. For `invoice` referenced as `i` I'm trying to use `id_customer_id`

invoice

```
    CREATE TABLE `invoice` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `system` int(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `number` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `customer_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `shipping_point_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `dv` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `drv` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `ctv` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `rv` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `transportation_zone_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_type` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_text` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_by` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `payment_terms` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `contract_discount` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `created_at` (`created_at`),
  KEY `invoice_type` (`invoice_type`),
  KEY `system` (`system`),
  KEY `transportation_zone_id` (`transportation_zone_id`),
  KEY `number` (`number`),
  KEY `customer_id` (`customer_id`),
  KEY `customer_id_created_at` (`customer_id`,`created_at`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3419336 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

invoice_items

```
   CREATE TABLE `invoice_items` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `invoice_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `position` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `quantity` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `material` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `material_group` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `mstav` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `manufacturer_part_number` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `manufacturer_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `supplier_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `plant` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `revenue` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `margin` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `currency` varchar(5) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `margin_percentage` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `disc_contractdisct` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nrcdaaprclientbstkd` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pret_mediu_variabilverpr` double(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `valza90cdaza90c` double(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `valzp0ccdazp01c` double(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `prcza90cdaza90c_p` double(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `prczp01cdazp01c_p` double(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pretlistaprlst` double(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `valra00cdara00c` double(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `valza91za91f` double(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ordered_by` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `invoice_id` (`invoice_id`),
  KEY `manufacturer_id` (`manufacturer_id`),
  KEY `material` (`material`),
  KEY `manufacturer_part_number` (`manufacturer_part_number`),
  KEY `invoice_id_manufacturer_id` (`invoice_id`,`manufacturer_id`),
  KEY `manufacturer_id_invoice_id_revenue` (`manufacturer_id`,`invoice_id`,`revenue`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6385754 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

**Update 2:**
After this all my selects went down from 36k to 4k of rows filtered, exactly what I needed.

```
"id"    "select_type"   "table" "type"  "possible_keys" "key"   "key_len"   "ref"   "rows"  "Extra"
"1" "SIMPLE"    "i" "range" "PRIMARY,created_at,customer_id,customer_id_created_at" "customer_id_created_at"    "9" \N  "4818"  "Using where; Using index"
"1" "SIMPLE"    "it"    "ref"   "invoice_id,manufacturer_id,invoice_id_manufacturer_id,manufacturer_id_invoice_id_revenue"  "invoice_id"    "4" "comercial.i.id"    "1" "Using where"
```

Comment: Provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE invoice_items` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE invoice`. Also please let us know which indexes you are trying to force to use.

Comment: *My query does not seem to bother for using indexes.* Explain claims that indices by `i.customer_id` and by `it.invoice_id` are used... see `key` column of EXPLAIN.

Comment: Only one index per table can be used. [How MySQL uses indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html), so you need [compound indexes](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index1). Seems like `invoice(customer_id,created_at)` and `invoice_items(manufacturer_id, invoice_id)` (maybe swapped order - depends which mysql chooses first) would be the most productive indexes for this query.

Comment: Added (manufacturuer_id,invoice_id,revenue) index on invoice_items and (customer_id,created_at) on invoice so now everything is great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the index `(manufacturuer_id,invoice_id,revenue)` to the `invoice_items` table.

This should help nudge the optimizer in the direction of using your existing `id_customer_id` index in the `invoice` table.

To see why it is not currently using the `id_customer_id` index, consider what it would need to do so. Since `id` is the leftmost column, that means you must have some information about the `id` column in order for it to gain much benefit from the index. As there is nothing in the WHERE clause about the `id` column, that means it would have to come form the JOIN.

In order to come from the join, the `invoice_items` table would have to be read first. This is where my suggested index comes into play.

Since you are providing the `manufacturer_id` in the WHERE clause, we start the new index there. Then the `invoice_id` as the second column is immediately accessible and so can be used to JOIN with the `invoice` table on your desired `id_customer_id` index.

Finally, by adding `revenue` to the end of my suggested index, you allow the SELECT clause to have easy access to that value, and so avoid a double lookup, which would also discourage the optimizer from choosing these indexes, if we didn't have that column.

As it is, without an index like I suggested the optimizer would have to do a a lot more work on the `invoice_items` table in order to get both the `invoice_id` and `revenue` columns for your given `manufacturer_id`.

Note that the single column index on `manufacturer_id` will be of little help in this situation, as although it allows quickly finding the primary key values for that `manufacturuer_id`, it must then perform a secondary lookup for the `invoice_id` and `revenue`, which is likely why it doesn't bother with that route.

Even worse, the `(invoice_id,manufacturer_id`) isn't useful either, as the `invoice_id` is first, which means to be useful we need to already have the `invoice_id`... but your index of `id_customer_id` in the `invoice` table also starts with that value, and so this index doesn't provide any benefit to the optimizer in terms of starting with it in order to JOIN to your desired index.

Hopefully that provides you with a good idea of why the optimizer is ignoring your efforts to use that particular index. Which, by the way, is a very good index to have, when combined with my suggested index.

Comment: This was extremely useful, did not think that the order of indexes does matter that much.

I've added the suggested index, also recreated one for invoice table and from 36k rows went down to 4k.